# Is convolution a coercive bilinear form in $L^2$ -space?

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, bilinear-form

This is one of the problems in functional analysis course I'm having. Suppose $f,g \in L^2(0,10)$. Then define a bilinear form
$$
B:(f,g)\mapsto \int_0^{10} f(x)g(10-x) dx.
$$
Now I have to find out whether this is coercive, eg. it fulfills the condition
$$
B(f,f) \geq C \| f \| ^2
$$
when $C>0$ and $f \in L^2(0,10)$, or not.

My attempt: I guess it is coercive. Since $L^2(0,10)$ is a Hilbert space we can write bilinear forms as
$$
B(f,g) = (f,Tg)
$$
where $T$ is a continuous linear operator. Here it is $Tg = g(10-x)$. I have a feeling that it is possible to find a constant $c>$ such that $Tg\geq c g$. Thus the coerciveness follows. I have not found such constant. My best guess is around $g(10-x) \geq \frac{1}{10} g(x)$ but I'm not sure about it.

Edit: I assume the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $T$ is an isometry. But there are $f\neq 0$ with $B(f,f) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \chi_{[0,5)}$. Then $f(x)f(10-x) \equiv 0$, so $B(f,f)=0 < 5=\lVert f \rVert_2^2$

Comment: Therefore it cannot be coercive, right.